# Extracting file names

Tags: regex, perl

I'm writing a script that takes a list of files from a directory, opens each one, and then searches for the lines that contain a filename with the .zip extension. Then I want to strip out just the filename from the line. Here is my code:

```
foreach (@fnames) {
    chomp ($_);
    open FILE, '<', "$_";
    @archives = grep { /.+?\.zip/ } <FILE>;

    foreach (@archives) {
        if ($_ =~ /("|>)(.+?)("|<)/) { push @files, $2; }
    }
}
```

The files I'm pulling the data from will contain the .zip filenames between either double quotes or angle brackets. This code is returning nothing, but I know the filenames are there. If I do a grep in the terminal I can see all of them, but the grep in Perl isn't giving me anything. Any ideas?

Comment: It works for me with a little test script. Have you tried dumping out `@archives` and `$_` inside the second loop to ensure that things are what you expect them to be?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Possible things wrong:

- `@fnames` is empty, because of some error in code you are not
  showing.
- `open FILE, ...` fails, but since you did not check the return value
  of the `open`, it fails silently, hence you don't know about it. Use `open ... or die $!`
- You have uppercase letters in your input, e.g. `ZIP`, and do not use
  the `/i` ignore case option in the grep. Btw, `.+?` in the beginning
  is fairly useless, unless you expect unwanted strings that begin with
  `.zip` (i.e. it only checks that there is at least one character before).
- The if-statement inside the second loop will only grab the first
  match.

Also:

- You should use a lexical filehandle with `open`.
- You should use strict and warnings, if you are not already doing so.
- `my @archives` and `my @files` in the proper lexical scope will help
  assure you get and keep the data you want.
- `$_ =~ /.../` can simply be written `/.../` for better readability
  (IMO).
- You do not (really) need a transition variable.
- `("|>)` is a redundant way of saying `[">]`.
- The `grep` is redundant processing. You can simply do:

---

```
while (<FILE>) {
      push @files, /[">](.*\.zip)["<]/ig;
}
```

In short:

```
my @files;
foreach my $file (@fnames) {
    chomp $file;
    open my $fh, '<', $file or die $!;
    while (<$fh>) {
        push @files, /[">](.*\.zip)["<]/ig;
    }
}
print "File names found: @files\n";
```

Comment: That worked great! Thanks for the help. I was using autodie which is why I didn't include die when I opened the file handle. I think the problem (as you stated above) was that the @archives array was not being populated. I'm still learning regex so I'm not familiar with all of the tips yet. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

In your script, you are not outputting anyting, you are just changing elements in an array. You have to `print` your lines, or use `Tie::File` to access each file directly as an array.